# SwiftUI View doesn't animate when updates UIHostingController constraint with animation

Tags: swiftui

I have a `MapView` (`SwiftUI View`) that embeds in `UIViewController` by `UIHostingController`, each time I press on the `Animation Button`, I expect that the `SwiftUI View` will update its height with animation.
However, when I update the `UIHostingController` height constraint with animation I notice that the `UIHostingController` changes with animation but the SwiftUI doesn't.
Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct MapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var bottomConstants: NSLayoutConstraint?
    let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MapView())
    let button = UIButton()

    var isExpand = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hostingViewController.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addChildController(hostingViewController)
        hostingViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let bottomConstants = hostingViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700)
        NSLayoutConstraint
            .activate([hostingViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                       bottomConstants,
                       hostingViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
                       hostingViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)])
        self.bottomConstants = bottomConstants

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitle("Animation", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = .black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        NSLayoutConstraint
            .activate([button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                       button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 100),
                       button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                       button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)])
    }

    @objc func selectButton() {
        if isExpand {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
                self.bottomConstants?.constant = 200
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
                self.bottomConstants?.constant = 700
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        isExpand.toggle()
    }
}

public extension UIViewController {
    func addChildController(_ childController: UIViewController) {
        addChild(childController)
        view.addSubview(childController.view)
        childController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func removeFromParentController() {
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Demo video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ukjDaSKzOpwB9MmnL4HQ5dc4UvYKhYX8/view?usp=sharing

I expect the SwiftUI MapView should update its height with animation when I call

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
     self.bottomConstants?.constant = 700
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```